# Is Adding css via jquery irrelevant because of addClass()?

Tags: jquery, css

From what I've read, when styling elements using jQuery, `addClass()` is faster performance-wise than using `css()`. I just want to know the benefits of using `css()` vs `addClass`.

Comment: Those are two different things, addClass adds a css-class and css-function adss inline css, both have their use cases.

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer about performance, I'd suggest you check it yourself if it's a concern (http://jsperf.com), although I doubt the difference will be perceptible unless you're changing tens of thousands of elements - but then you have another problem. With regard to the benefit of `addClass()`, it's simply that it avoids having CSS logic within your JS, which is good for separation of concerns. It also avoids inline `style` attributes, which is good practice, although sometimes unavoidable.

Comment: I think the benefits are for example that you can set multiple rules in class and then just addClass(yourclass) instead of having to add multiple options all the time..

Answer (score 0):

`css()` adds the css values inline. While `addClass()` set a predefined class. Therefore you need to have a class to append and you can not make dynamic styles. So the `css()` function is handy when you have dynamic propertie values or when you don't want to create a class for 1 value change for example.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `.css()` and `addClass()` functions stands different purpose same as inline style and CSS class in HTML.

inline Style - It is to apply on single HTML element
CSS class - It is to apply same styling on multiple HTML elements with more controlled way

if you want to change style of one HTML element with few attributes then you should go for `css()` function otherwise create CSS class and apply it to mutliple HTML elements using `addClass()`

Answer (score 0):

In simple words,

`css()` sets inline CSS attribute by attribute, that are not preset but are set during the execution of the code,

whereas,

`addClass()` method adds a class to the DOM structure during runtime, that can have a predifined CSS, or can be defined.

In short, `css()` sets properties one by one that appear as inline CSS, whereas, `addClass()` method adds a class to the HTML element, and that class can be pre-configured in the external or internal stylesheets. So, `addClass()` method takes less time of execution and keeps the DOM structure clean.